# Redirecting in .htaccess

Tags: php, linux, .htaccess

In the htaccess I want to redirect all URL's that end with ?p=X to go to the home page. Here are some examples below which I want to go to the home page but I want to have just 1 statement for all that works:

```
Redirect 301 "/products/?p=4771" "/"
Redirect 301 "/products/?p=5226" "/"
Redirect 301 "/products/?p=4771" "/"
Redirect 301 "/products/?p=4973" "/"
Redirect 301 "/products/?p=5226" "/"
```

Comment: Do you mind posting the answer on this site that is related to the code I posted above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)p=\d+(?:&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^products/?$    /?  [NC,R=301,L]
```